# Ruby on rails how can I search my table by keyword?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this table relationship like:

certificate belongs_to programs

certificate belongs_to users

And I have a form in the certificate view page to get the keyword params.

I want to search for user name and email by the form.

How can I get this done in controller?

```html
<%= form_tag admin_program_path(@program), :method => :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :keyword, params[:keyword], :placeholder => "Search by name or email", :class => "form-control rounded" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :class => "btn btn-outline-secondary" %>
<% end %>
```

I was trying as below, but it can't work.
Please help me.

```html
    @certificates = @program.certificates.includes(:user).order("id DESC")
    if params[:keyword].present?
      keyword = "%#{params[:keyword].strip}%"
      @certificates = @certificates.user.where('name LIKE ? OR email LIKE ?', keyword, keyword)
    end
```

Comment: you can use this to apply as a filter 
    `@program.certificates.joins(:user).where("lower(users.name) LIKE ? OR lower(users.email) LIKE ?", "%#{params[:keyword].downcase}%", "%#{params[:keyword].downcase}%")`

Answer (score 0):

You are not querying on the `users` table properly. You need to join the `users` table with the `certificates` table and modify your where statement and use `users.` on `name` and `email` as these attributes belong to the `users` table.
This should work:

```
@certificates = @program.certificates.joins(:user).includes(:user).order("id DESC")
if params[:keyword].present?
  keyword = "%#{params[:keyword].strip}%"
  @certificates = @certificates.where('users.name LIKE ? OR users.email LIKE ?', keyword, keyword)
end
```

Comment: It shows undefined local variable or method `user' on joins(user)

Comment: @ChaosTW Missed adding `:` before user earlier. updated! check now.

Comment: I found that if I use joins(:user), the order("id DESC") has to change into order("certificates.id DESC")

Answer (score 0):

1: find all users by keyword

2: find by found certificates users' ids

`users = User.where('name LIKE ? OR email LIKE ?', keyword, keyword)`

`@certificates = @certificates.where(user_id: users.pluck(:id))`

**OR** joins the users table and use something like `@certificates.where('name LIKE ?', keyword)`